# Excel - Merge two columns row by row

Tags: excel, merge, row, excel-2007

I would like to copy the contents of a column and paste it into two columns merged. But when I paste the content, it is duplicated in two columns. I would not have to select each line pairs to be able to merge. Is that possible?

[image: Excel description]

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible:

**Initial data**

[image]

**Step1** select range to copy (in my case `D4:D19`), copy it. Than select `G4:H4`, *right mouse click -> Paste Special -> Paste formulas*.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]